# Windows 10 and multiple virtual desktops with different icons on each desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-desktop

I want the ability to have multiple virtual desktops I can switch between and have **different icons on the desktop** and wallpapers on each of them. E.g. "Development" where I have all my development tools icons on the desktop and a "Games", where I have my games visible. I do have two monitors in my setup.

I know Windows 10 actually does have virtual desktops, but it shows the same icons on all desktops - pretty useless in my opinion.

Is there any third-party application that has solved this in a good way? I seem unable to find any at least on Google and Microsoft Store?

Answer (score 0):

Try VirtualWin, I have been using it for a number of years.

[Download VirtualWin](https://virtuawin.sourceforge.io/)

It is free and supports upto 9 desktops and you configure the layout. The shortcut keys are amazing, I can move to a different desktop  on eahc of the 4 directions using the keys.  I can also move a window this way to another desktop just with shortcuts.  You ca also pin application on individual desktops.

**First page of setup**

[image]

[Download SL Desktop Name module](https://virtuawin.sourceforge.io/?page_id=50) and follow the instructions in **readme.1st**

You can set up text and colours of the icon/label for each desktop.  However, it only flashes when you change the desktop.  You can configure the position and duration of visibility.

**Module Configuration**

[image: Screenshot of module]

There are other modules, which I haven't tried, to have individual background colour or even individual wallpaper for each desktop.